# How to get alertdialg selected item in textview?

Tags: android, textview, android-alertdialog

Hello I have set text in my xml using settext property,and on textview setonclick listener I set the alertdialog,it works fine till click on textview and appearance of items,but when I click on any of item ,its not set on my textview,so how to do it?

```
final String[] items = new String[] {"jkl", "abc", "Tdg"};
final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter123 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, items);

sp3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View w) {

        new AlertDialog.Builder(RegistrationForm.this).setTitle("Select option").setAdapter(adapter123, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }).create().show();
    }
});
```

Comment: before dialog.dismiss() just set text in textview using settext().

Comment: can you put your full code here?

Comment: but i define in my xml also,

Comment: where have you set Text on the click of item?? put line in onClick to setText in your textview

Comment: the xml value need to be changed on click of item..so you need to code for it

Comment: @SweetWisherツ thanks but arash's answer solved my problem,and no need to code to change for xml value

Comment: that is what I was saying ..**YOU NEED TO CODE = sp3.settext(Items[which])** in onClick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are just dismissing your dialolg inside `onClick`, You need to set text inside it.

```
@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

     dialog.dismiss();
}
```

change it to :

```
@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

     sp3.settext(Items[which])
     dialog.dismiss();
}
```